# can we use android/ios sdk in crossplatforms like react native/flutter/ionic

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, ionic-framework, mapmyindia-api

**mapmyindia(mmi)** provides map sdks for android and for ios and map apis for web
Sdks are free to use but APIs aren't
But what about hybrid
Can i use android or ios sdks of mmi(not api) in ionic/flutter/react native(it will b a great help if u mention if its possible for these all 3 cases,bcse according to that I'll b choosing my framework)
If so how, they didn't provide documentation for hybrid apps.
below is ios sdk link of mmi:
https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/ios/vector-map-sdk
and android:
https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/android/vector-maps-sdk

Comment: It is possible to use native code in React Native. Look at: https://medium.com/@manishahire/how-to-use-android-code-in-react-native-e0c6ce0dd286